# How to create a Super User Account on AWS's RDS Mysql?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The Master user has limited permissions on RDS.

I need SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privileges, and I don't know how to add them to my user.

Tried this solution from another question:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'root'@'14.156.117.179';
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

Even trying to give SUPER privilege gives me an error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'masteruser'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 5):

A quote from [RDS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/):

> Amazon RDS is a managed service, and it doesn't provide SYS access (SUPER privileges).

So, the answer is that you cannot get `SUPER` privileges there.

Comment: AWS Customer Support may able to direct your to SALES for additional services.